# How to get all data from firebase with firesharp

Tags: c#, firebase, fire-sharp

I have user_table in firebase, I want get all node data as list from user_table.

I can get all data with

```
FirebaseResponse response = await client.GetTaskAsync("User_Table\");
```

, then I can not serialize json data to object

```
 FirebaseResponse response = await client.GetTaskAsync("User_Table\\");
 List<UserList> usr = (List<UserList>)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(response.ToString(), (typeof(List<UserList>)));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using a `dictionary` and `foreach`?

You can also try to follow this tutorial from YouTube
https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=oeblTSuBjSo&t=1s

Example:

```
FirebaseResponse response = await client.GetAsync("users");
Dictionary<string, Class> data = response.ResultAs<Dictionary<string, Data>>();
return data;
```